# group list into lists when sum of list under threshold

Tags: python, algorithm, nested-lists

I have a list:

```
[(14, 2), (14, 2), (16, 2), (14, 2), (15, 2), (15, 2), (21, 2), (15, 2), (18, 2), (15, 2), (19, 2), (25, 2), (22, 2), (17, 2), (31, 2), (26, 2), (21, 2), (25, 2), (29, 2), (33, 2), (25, 2), (23, 2), (25, 2), (19, 2), (12, 2), (29, 2), (18, 2), (21, 2), (13, 2), (13, 2), (18, 2), (11, 2), (12, 2), (20, 2), (23, 2), (17, 2), (14, 2), (17, 2), (12, 2), (13, 2), (15, 2), (21, 2), (15, 2), (19, 2), (22, 2), (16, 2), (16, 2), (13, 2), (17, 2), (18, 2), (20, 2), (18, 2), (13, 2), (13, 2), (18, 2), (14, 2), (13, 2), (22, 2), (14, 2), (25, 2), (22, 2), (9, 2), (18, 2), (22, 2), (19, 2), (13, 2), (14, 2), (15, 2), (13, 2), (17, 2), (21, 2), (18, 2), (21, 2), (18, 2), (15, 2), (16, 2), (13, 2), (16, 2), (16, 2), (15, 2), (11, 2), (24, 2), (15, 2), (12, 2), (20, 2), (21, 2), (21, 2), (14, 2), (11, 2), (26, 2), (17, 2), (21, 2), (16, 2), (13, 2), (15, 2), (13, 2), (12, 2), (22, 2), (16, 2), (13, 2), (13, 2), (22, 2), (12, 2), (16, 2), (16, 2), (21, 2), (19, 2), (15, 2), (16, 2), (16, 2), (13, 2), (14, 2), (14, 2), (20, 2), (14, 2), (20, 2), (13, 2), (19, 2), (20, 2), (17, 2), (17, 2), (25, 2), (22, 2), (22, 2), (22, 2), (14, 2), (19, 2), (20, 2), (16, 2), (13, 2), (19, 2), (16, 2), (12, 2), (18, 2), (20, 2), (19, 2), (18, 2), (15, 2), (22, 2), (18, 2), (20, 2), (14, 2), (19, 2), (16, 2), (18, 2), (28, 2), (14, 2), (17, 2), (17, 2), (23, 2), (18, 2), (24, 2), (17, 2), (18, 2), (18, 2), (22, 2)]
```

And I want my output to be a list of lists where every sub-list is the number of elements that can be added together without being over a certain threshold and only stored as the sum (of each element):

Example, if the threshold is 50 (inclusive):

```
[[16, 16, 18], [16, 17, 17], [23, 17], [20, 17], [21, 27], [24, 19], [33], [28], [23, 27], [31], [35], [27], [25], [27, 21] ...]
```

The second value of the tuple may vary. Preferred as a list comprehension.

EDIT:

As requested, my original code which I want to cleanup/optimize:

```
padding = len("Packages () ") + math.floor(math.log10(len(apps))+1)
line_length = columns - (padding * 2) - 2

spacings = 2
element_length = [item for sublist in [list(a) for a in zip([len(i) for i in apps],[i for i in itertools.repeat(spacings, len([len(i) for i in apps]))])] for item in sublist]
limits = []
outer_limit = 0
while line_length <= sum(element_length):
    while line_length >= sum(element_length[0:outer_limit]):
        outer_limit += 1
    limits.append(outer_limit - 1)
    element_length = element_length[outer_limit - 1:]
    outer_limit = 0

  message = ""
  a = 0
  b = 0
  for amount in limits:
      b += math.ceil(amount / 2)
      message += (" " * spacings).join(apps[a:b]) + ("\n" + " " * padding)
      a = b

  print("Packages ({}) {}".format(len(apps), message))
```

Comment: is there any reason why a list comprehension? it might be less readable that way

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? It seems like you just want us to do it for you

Comment: I suspect that there is a more elegant solution that's based on itertools.groupby but I don't know how that would look like hence the question.
I have a solution that is based on list comprehensions + 2 while loops but I don't like the complexity of that solution. I didn't mention it because It's not (directly) part of my question.

Comment: What should happen if you have a tuple that is over 50 itself, e.g. `(50, 2)`? Or is that guaranteed to not happen?

Comment: Can you post that solution @What and we can see if it can be simplified

Comment: @mapeters it's very unlikely though possible. The best case would be to still contain it in a list of one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pretty simple way of doing that with just a single for-loop:

```
tups = [(14, 2), (14, 2), (16, 2), (14, 2)]
threshold = 50
result = [[]]
for tup in tups:
    tupSum = sum(tup)
    # Start a new sublist if adding this tuple's sum would exceed the threshold
    if tupSum + sum(result[-1]) > threshold:
        result.append([])
    result[-1].append(tupSum)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with the reduce function from functools:

```
a = [(14, 2), (14, 2), (16, 2), (14, 2), (15, 2), (15, 2), (21, 2), (15, 2), (18, 2), (15, 2), (19, 2), (25, 2), (22, 2), (17, 2), (31, 2), (26, 2), (21, 2), (25, 2), (29, 2), (33, 2), (25, 2), (23, 2), (25, 2), (19, 2), (12, 2), (29, 2), (18, 2), (21, 2), (13, 2), (13, 2), (18, 2), (11, 2), (12, 2), (20, 2), (23, 2), (17, 2), (14, 2), (17, 2), (12, 2), (13, 2), (15, 2), (21, 2), (15, 2), (19, 2), (22, 2), (16, 2), (16, 2), (13, 2), (17, 2), (18, 2), (20, 2), (18, 2), (13, 2), (13, 2), (18, 2), (14, 2), (13, 2), (22, 2), (14, 2), (25, 2), (22, 2), (9, 2), (18, 2), (22, 2), (19, 2), (13, 2), (14, 2), (15, 2), (13, 2), (17, 2), (21, 2), (18, 2), (21, 2), (18, 2), (15, 2), (16, 2), (13, 2), (16, 2), (16, 2), (15, 2), (11, 2), (24, 2), (15, 2), (12, 2), (20, 2), (21, 2), (21, 2), (14, 2), (11, 2), (26, 2), (17, 2), (21, 2), (16, 2), (13, 2), (15, 2), (13, 2), (12, 2), (22, 2), (16, 2), (13, 2), (13, 2), (22, 2), (12, 2), (16, 2), (16, 2), (21, 2), (19, 2), (15, 2), (16, 2), (16, 2), (13, 2), (14, 2), (14, 2), (20, 2), (14, 2), (20, 2), (13, 2), (19, 2), (20, 2), (17, 2), (17, 2), (25, 2), (22, 2), (22, 2), (22, 2), (14, 2), (19, 2), (20, 2), (16, 2), (13, 2), (19, 2), (16, 2), (12, 2), (18, 2), (20, 2), (19, 2), (18, 2), (15, 2), (22, 2), (18, 2), (20, 2), (14, 2), (19, 2), (16, 2), (18, 2), (28, 2), (14, 2), (17, 2), (17, 2), (23, 2), (18, 2), (24, 2), (17, 2), (18, 2), (18, 2), (22, 2)]

from functools import reduce
b = list(reduce(lambda a,b:a+[[b]] if sum(a[-1])+b>50 else a[:-1]+[a[-1]+[b]],map(sum,a),[[]]))
print(b) 

# [[16, 16, 18], [16, 17, 17], [23, 17], [20, 17], [21, 27], [24, 19], [33], [28], [23, 27], [31], [35], [27], [25], [27, 21], [14, 31], [20, 23], [15, 15, 20], [13, 14, 22], [25, 19], [16, 19, 14], [15, 17], [23, 17], [21, 24], [18, 18], [15, 19], [20, 22], [20, 15, 15], [20, 16], [15, 24], [16, 27], [24, 11], [20, 24], [21, 15], [16, 17, 15], [19, 23], [20, 23], [20, 17], [18, 15], [18, 18], [17, 13], [26, 17], [14, 22], [23, 23], [16, 13], [28, 19], [23, 18], [15, 17, 15], [14, 24], [18, 15, 15], [24, 14], [18, 18], [23, 21], [17, 18], [18, 15, 16], [16, 22], [16, 22], [15, 21], [22, 19], [19, 27], [24, 24], [24, 16], [21, 22], [18, 15], [21, 18], [14, 20], [22, 21], [20, 17], [24, 20], [22, 16], [21, 18], [20, 30], [16, 19], [19, 25], [20, 26], [19, 20], [20, 24]]
```